# Is there a word for something that is perfectly or aptly named (the opposite of a "misnomer")?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

My spouse took a picture of a bird with a yellow head and a black body. The bird is called Yellow-headed Blackbird. He wants to say that the bird is aptly named. I am looking for a single word that means perfectly (aptly) named.

If *misnomer* is connected to a meaning that is wrong, is there a word for a meaning that is "spot on"? I've done a Google search to try to find the antonym (in this sense) of "misnomer" with no success.

Comment: What do you mean by "opposite"?

Comment: I am looking for an antonym. If  misnomer is connected to a meaning that is wrong, is there a word for a meaning that is "spot on"?

Comment: A misnomer is not a meaning which is wrong but a *name* which is wrong: *present participle*, for instance, which has no tense or inherent time reference.

Comment: I suppose that because misnomer is an incorrect name usage, the opposite is simply a name (and by virtue of not being a misnomer is the opposite).  You could emphasise the fact that the name is correct using something like "apt name".

Comment: If you were to explain the context a bit more, we might be able to try and help. What are you wanting to say, and what type of 'name' are you referring to: the name of a person, house, object, ...?

Comment: Antonyms are not automatically generated by a machine. "Opposite" only works for terms that lie on a semantic cline, like _hot/cold, warm/cool, boiling/freezing_, etc. _Misnomer_ is already a negative; which part should be reversed? Not Negative? Not Named? Not Appropriately named?

Comment: I appreciate the clarity.  @Trevor- My spouse took a picture of a bird with a yellow head and a black body. The bird is called Yellow-headed Blackbird. He wants to say that the bird is aptly named. I am looking for a single word that means perfectly (aptly) named.

Comment: I am confused by the votes to close the post as "not a real question." If my question is vague, I am happy to clarify. I appreciate Trevor giving me the opportunity to explain my original question. Is that clarification sufficient to establish this as a real question? Again, thank you to everyone who responded.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a proper answer – that is, a word whose part of speech and style of usage is like that of *misnomer*, except opposite in meaning – but consider the following terms.
• *[bon mot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_mot)*, a borrowing from French *bon mot* (“good word”), with less-relevant English meaning “A clever saying, phrase or witticism; often, a witty riposte in dialogue”
• *[apropos](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apropos#English)*, “Of an appropriate or pertinent nature”
• *[autological](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autological#Adjective)*, “Of a phrase (especially an adjective), possessing the property it describes” [with the notion that a word that possesses the property it describes cannot be a misnomer]
• *[mot juste](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mot_juste#Noun)*, “Exactly the right word or phrasing”
• *[aptronym](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aptronym#Noun)*, a slightly obscure word that means “A name that is aptly suited to its owner”, or *[aptonym](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aptonym#Noun)*, “A proper name that aptly describes the occupation or character of the person...”

Comment: Thank you. Is there a single word that means perfectly (aptly) named?

Comment: @Sam – Perhaps; anyway, I've edited to add *[mot juste](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mot_juste#Noun)*, which is really what I meant to think of when I thought of *[bon mot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_mot#Noun)*.

Comment: Thank you Jwpat7. That's wonderful. I see there is a message saying that the question is closed. I hope you will be able to read my response. I'm grateful for your insight.

Comment: _Mot juste_ would be the mot juste were it not deux mots.