# Antonym of "misnomer"

Tags: slang, antonyms

I believe I have heard the word "nomer" used before? It is not in the dictionary, but I was under the assumption that "nomer" was the opposite of "misnomer"? From the thesaurus references I have seen, there are no antonyms for the word "misnomer."

Is what I have heard just slang for "correct name"?

Comment: In the same way that "nonymous" is the opposite of "anonymous" :) The only think I can think of, as applied to people, is **moniker**. But it implies an alias. I think

Comment: Misnomer means incorrect name while a word such as "rumor" means implied, but not confirmed. I am trying to find a word that means implied.  In the statement "go get 'em tiger", tiger is a misnomer as the little league baseball player is not a real tiger, but is implied.  Saying Babe Ruth was a drunk is not a misnomer, but a ??  Fact? not really proven.  So it's implied that Ruth drank a lot.  So would I say "the nomer that Ruth drank a lot has been..."?  Trying to find a word that would fit where I am using "nomer". "Rumor" just doesn't seem to fit for me.

Comment: Possibile duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116165/opposite-of-misnomer

Comment: Asking for the antonym of *misnomer* is a bit like asking the antonym of *mistake*. Any ideas? A *take* perhaps!

Comment: My main goal with my question is to find out if "nomer" can be used as a word, albeit a slang word?

Comment: An [aptronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym) (also: aptonym) or charactonym is a name aptly suited to its owner.

Comment: Couldn't possibly be _misternomer_, could it? :-)

Comment: @JohnLawler - That was my first thought.

Comment: Hello, Dreifort. The statement 'It is not in the dictionary' is dangerously imprecise (have you tried OED, for instance?) It is also incorrect, if one concedes Urban Dictionary to be a dictionary. Not showing details (which dictionaries have you checked in" Which thesauri?) is not the best way to present your query.

Comment: @JohnLawler Please excuse my naivety, but what joke or pun did you intend with `misternomer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Aptronym** (also listed in a comment by @Jim)
2. **Apt** name (the root word of aptronym)
3. **[True name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name)** (seriously, it is a real issue in many contexts)
4. ***Apropos*** name (also suggested in [this closed question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116165/opposite-of-misnomer))
5. In some contexts, the antonym might be **[onomatopoeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia)**.
6. Onomatopoeia is a form of an **[ideophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone)**, which has a broader meaning but probably still not so broad as to be a perfect antonym to misnomer.
7. **[Phonosemantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism)**, literally "sound meaning", has a broader meaning than ideophone, but it means that the word itself has meaning rather than word is the appropriate word to describe the object, so it is an imperfect antonym.

### I give up

The search for this word brings up some difficult philosophical problems, such as the difference between an object and our perception of the object. I originally thought this would be a lighthearted topic, not a cliff-dive into ontology, epistemology, and phenomenology! I need some chocolate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you would have heard the word "nomer" used in a serious english context before. It's not an English word.

Listing of *misnomer* on [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=misnomer&allowed_in_frame=0):

> mid-15c., "mistaken identification of an accused or convicted person," from Anglo-French, Old French mesnomer "to misname, wrongly name," noun use of infinitive, from mes- "wrongly" (see ***mis-*** (2)) + nomer "to name," from Latin nominare "***nominate***" (see nominate). For noun use of French infinitives, see ***waiver***.

If you follow the [***waiver***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=waiver&allowed_in_frame=0) link, you will see the following etymology:

> "act of waiving," 1620s (modern usage is often short for waiver clause); from Anglo-French legal usage of infinitive as a noun (see waive). Baseball waivers is recorded from 1907. Other survivals of noun use of infinitives in Anglo-French legalese include disclaimer, merger, rejoinder, misnomer, ouster, retainer, attainder.

So *misnomer* is a borrowed Anglo-French legal noun use of an infinitive, it was not coined from a pre-existing "nomer" english word. I would find it odd to hear the word *nomer* used as a kind of antonym.

Another English word with a similar etymology is *renown* (from re- "repeatedly" (see re-) + nomer "to name."). *Nominate*, of course, is another word with a similar root, but comes directly from Latin.

I agree with Martin Krzywinski's comment to your question as to the closest antonym. *Moniker* fits well to me. Although he says it implies an alias, but if some word you're trying to use is a misnomer, then it's appropriate to find an alternate word with is a "correct name" so by definition that's also an alias for what you're trying to describe.

Comment: Renown might work for the context I am searching for.  Would you say that the late 1960s were renown for drug use in America? It certainly would be a misnomer to say every American took drugs as not everyone was proven to have partaken in drug use.  To me renown would imply that a majority of Americans took drugs in the 1960s... but again, that's more than likely not factually correct.  What word would best fit (besides more common words such as "rumor" or "imply") that suggests Americans took drugs in the late 1960s?  That is the context for which I am trying to find a word such as "nomer."

Comment: @Dreifort you would use the adjective form: The late 1960s were *renowned* for drug use in America. I don't think you've used *misnomer* quite correctly — *mistake* would be a better word choice in that next sentence you wrote. *Misnomer* is applied to a specific word or term, not a concept. You could instead say "it would be a misnomer to call the decade the Psychedelic 60s because…"

Comment: @Dreifot The important point is, however, that not all words have antonyms. There's no word that necessarily fits in every sentence construction with the opposite meaning of *misnomer*. In my example you might write "it would be appropriate to call the decade the Psychedelic 60s because…" (Or perhaps, tying everything together: "It would be an appropriate moniker to call…")

Comment: Your statement 'It's not an English word' might cause a few arguments hereabouts if OP claims to have heard it. Can you offer a definition of 'word' that supports your claim? Urban Dictionary claims that [nomer] 'is a shortened version of the derogatory slang term _no namer_'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The way I define a proper English word is that it is found in the OED, Merriam-Webster, Cambridge, or other major dictionary. I don't consider the Urban Dictionary to be an authoritative resource. We could talk a lot about whatever utterances or slang that English speakers have ever used, but if they aren't understood by a significant portion of English speakers, I don't consider it a "serious" English word.

Comment: Music to my ears, ghoppe. But can you find an authoritative work that actually gives this definition? I've tried for ages. (Even OED say that 'a string's non-inclusion in this work does not preclude its being a word' (paraphrased somewhat).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, that's why I try to qualify my statements with "serious english context" and "proper English word." Unless we're specifically talking about local slang or neologisms, it seems counterproductive to spread too wide a net in deciding what is an "English word".

Comment: But 'serious English context' and 'proper English word' are equally if not even more subjective and loose. I want a dictionary definition stressing a certain level of frequency of occurrence in various corpora, say. So I can trot it out when people say 'Any string that has ever been printed is a word'.

Answer (score 0):

*Nomer* would fit nicely into the same category of humorous back-formed antonymic coinages as *gruntled, couth,* and *kempt.* A more serious suggestion would be *orthonym* (not in OED, but in [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=orthonym)—follow the link and upvote Uttam Maharjan’s lone definition).